# Southern country, be wild! (7)

Tags: cryptic-clues

I don't know how hard this one will be.  Hopefully, not too hard.

Southern country, be wild! (7)

Comment: List of countries in the Southern Hemisphere: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Hemisphere

Comment: You seem to be good at inventing cryptic-clues. Maybe consider collecting more of them and putting them into a proper cross-word? Or some other, more complex puzzle? Somehow, "single-clue" puzzles are a bit, hmm, meagre?

Comment: @BmyGuest, yes, you are probably right.  I will try to bundle them, maybe in groups of 5?  I'm not sure I have the chops to make a full-up crossword (let alone figure out how to post the image).

Comment: @Jiminion Easiest way to do a crossword puzzle is to use a spread-sheet program like Excel or GoogleSheets. Make the cells square, arrange your solution, then colorize the cells. Once done, do a screen-snap-shot and save the image. Uploading the image to StackExchange should not be an issue... Just use the "picture" icon when typing your question. Having said all this: Are you using the site with a mobile device only? Then it might actually be trickier... But you might also consider cooperation with somebody else here on site. You do the clues, they the cross-word...

Comment: I basically am working and sometimes something hits me.  But I will try to add them to a list first.  (I loved the Cryptic Crosswords that used to be in 'The Atlantic'.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> Bolivia?

Southern country

> The definition

be wild!

> B + Olivia, as in Olivia Wilde the actress.

Comment: If so, the "wild" part isn't really kosher in a cryptic clue. (Apart from the obvious issue, there's also the capitalization.)

Comment: @Deusovi, but it is not really wild, is it?  It's wild!

Answer (score 4):

Thinking maybe:

> Texas Hold 'Em?

Southern country

> Texas was a country

be wild!

> Poker has wild cards

7

> Texas Hold 'Em has 7 cards. As an aside, Texas was also the 7th state admitted to the confederacy, a separate country.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the (#) in cryptic-clues always refers to the solution length? So (7) has a 7-letter solution. No other 7 meaning...

Comment: @BmyGuest, ah, thanks for the tip. I'll delete or modify with another answer if I come up with one.

Comment: I like the original take on the answer, though.